# How to get praise from customers?

Tags: colleagues, motivation, customer-service, consulting

I work in the consulting firm of a big concern with different departments. Inside these departments are really big differences in speed, quality, consumer service etc. My department is well known and famous for a brilliant consumer service (including: consumer wishes, flexibility, consumer loyalty).

Now my colleagues have a problem. Because we exist for 3 years now and we work together with long-term customers, the customers now think our high quality work is going to be standard. For us, internal it is standard, but compared to the company we are more than standard. That is the image we want to still get seen by our customers. So the consequences are that my colleagues won´t get as much praise as in the beginning time. The clients are still happy, but they don´t tell this directly. If we send them an e-mail with the evaluation document, we are still on a high level. What is the solution to get more praise? Praise is motivation for them but they want that the clients say that volunteer.

Maybe we should change the consultants for the customers (rotating)? So what can we do to get more praised?

Answer (score 6):

> What is the solution to get more praise?

You answer it right here:

> If we send them an e-mail with the evaluation document, we are still on a high level.

For the overwhelming majority of workers in the world, no one consistently pats them on the back and says "great work." This is normally limited to those who actually do that sort of work.

If your team is new they won't be at this point. Your team members really shouldn't expect this either.

> Praise is motivation for them but they want that the clients say that volunteer.

Hopefully your employees have more motivation than simply this.

> Because we exist for 3 years now and we work together with long-term customers, the customers now think our high quality work is going to be standard

One perspective is that if you have consistently high quality work the fact that you have not lost any customers is a praise in itself for your department.

> Maybe we should change the consultants for the customers (rotating)? So what can we do to get more praised?

One thing you can do is be more proactive on *internal* praise. Making sure the newer colleagues receive similar accolades for their work. But also make sure you do not compromise your quality of work for this.